# Inductor time variable current

Tags: current, ac, inductor

At t0<0 the current through the inductor was 0.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwwpAB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At time t0 we introduce a current source and a resistor to the solenoid

The current through the inductor will begin rising exponentially.If we change the value of I1 some time before L1 becomes a short circuit:(at t1)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS0jiI.png)</sup>
How will the current behave then?

Comment: Homework?  What have you tried to solve the problem and where are you stuck?

Comment: Not homework I am just trying to understand how inductors work under AC.

Comment: It will behave exactly like a first order L-R circuit with the initial condition being the inductor current at t1.  You know the initial current IL(t1) and you know the final current (I1) and you know how the current will approach the final value, right?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470171/how-can-there-be-a-current-without-a-voltage/470182#470182

Comment: MrV, Can you amend your question to include what you developed *before* the change took place to swap out \$I_1\$ with \$I_2\$? What did you do and what results did you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general nodal equation is:

$$\frac{V_t}{R_1}+\frac1{L_1}\int V_t\:\text{d}t+I_{L\left(t=t_i\right)}=I_{t=t_i}\tag{1}\label{e1}$$

Where \$I_{t=t_i}\$ is your current source value at \$t=t_i\$ and \$I_{L\left(t=t_i\right)}\$ is the inductor current's initial condition at \$t=t_i\$. I'm keeping this in a general form, since you'll need it twice: at \$t=t_{_0}=0^+\,\text{s}\$ and at \$t=t_{_1}\$.

Putting this into differential form gives:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\, t}V_t+ \frac{R_1}{L_1}\,V_t=0\:\text{V}\cdot\text{s}^{-1}\tag{2}\label{e2}$$

For your first situation at \$t_{_0}\$, you know that the initial condition is \$V_{t=0^+\,\text{s}}=I_1\,R_1\$. So you can solve the differential equation for \$V_t\:\mid_0^{t_1}\$. And it immediately follows from KCL that \$I_{L\left(t\right)}\mid_0^{t_1}=I_1-\frac{V_t\:\mid_0^{t_1}}{R_1}\$, from which you can develop the equation for the current in the inductor.

Similarly, the exact same equation found in Eq. \$\ref{e2}\$ also still applies in your newer situation. However, for \$t\ge t_{_1}\$, you will have a new initial condition, \$V_{t_{_1}}\:\mid_0^{t_1}\$ (which you can easily compute from the earlier voltage equation.) Getting a result here is the same process, though. Just don't forget to do your substitutions to simplify and keep track of your time offsets. Keep in mind this is a new \$V_{t}\:\mid_{t_1}^{\infty}\$ equation. Again, it immediately follows from KCL that \$I_{L\left(t\right)}\mid_{t_1}^{\infty}=I_2-\frac{V_{t}\:\mid_{t_1}^{\infty}}{R_1}\$.