# Inductor behavior in DC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, inductor

An inductor in a pure DC circuit once steady state is reached has a zero volts across it.

In the figure below, the inductor will have a voltage which is not zero

[image]

Why isn't VL zero?

Comment: **Once steady state is reached**: Yes, and $$\lim_{t\to \infty} v_L(t)=-i(0)R\cdot 0 + V \cdot 0 =0,$$ where's the problem here?

Comment: *An inductor in a pure DC circuit* **once steady state is reached** *has a zero volts across it.*

Comment: Thank you Andy. I was trying to understand DC-DC converters how the inductors have voltage, Because the switching frequency is much more than the time constant. Very clear.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470171/how-can-there-be-a-current-without-a-voltage/470182#470182

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all embedded in the simple inductor formula: -

$$V = L\cdot\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

So, when \$\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ has become zero (as when a battery is applied to an inductor in series with a resistor and a length of time has passed), the pure inductor voltage has to be zero and all the voltage from the battery appears across the resistor.

> *I was trying to understand DC-DC converters how the inductors have
> voltage*

Or, in a boost converter, if you apply a voltage across the inductor, current ramps up at a rate determined by V/L. Eventually too much current is passed for the supply voltage to sustain it but, for a short period of time (usually microseconds or tens of microseconds), that current is used to store energy in the magnetic field: -

$$\text{Energy, W} = \dfrac{I^2\cdot L}{2}$$

Once the voltage supply is disconnected, that energy can be used to charge a capacitor up to quite high voltages hence, you can make a boost converter that converts a DC input voltage of a few volts to anything up to tens or hundreds of volts.