# If inductors opposes any change in electrical current, how can the magnetic field vary with time if the current is varying with time?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, inductor, magnetics

When I looked the definition of the inductors, I saw that:

1. It opposes any change in electrical current.
2. If the current is varying with time, the magnetic field is varying with time.

So if 1. sentence is one of the its characteristics, how could sentence 2.  could be true? Don't inductors oppose any change in electrical current?

Comment: It's semantics: they **try** to oppose but not fully perpetually oppose. If your version was true then an inductor would behave like an open-circuit and, taking it to extremes, we would never see light from distant stars (in fact light could not exist). It's that fundamental.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand that why we use them if they're not good opposes change in current? @Andy aka

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470171/how-can-there-be-a-current-without-a-voltage/470182#470182

Comment: @XcellentEEE Why would we use them if they completely stopped current (my response). An open-circuit also stops current and clearly, an inductor is not an open-circuit and, neither is a wire (but it has inductance).

Comment: No, I'm not saying 'stopped current', I'm tried to say 'opposes change in current', if current is not constant. For instance if current change in time and at t=0, 4A, t=1 8A. and go on... Current values always changing why we use them? Isn't it without them current same? @Andy aka

Comment: I think your real question boils down to "why do we use inductors" @XcellentEEE

Comment: Resistors also oppose current, but **some** current still passes through.  The mechanism is different but the results are similar for steady state signals in inductors.  You can think of an inductor as a dynamic resistor in that as the currents frequency goes up, the inductors opposition goes up.  This is called its reactance. \$X=wL\$

Comment: It looks like that, yes :( @Andy aka

Comment: Thank you so much. @Aaron

Comment: Mass opposes acceleration. And yet, when we apply force to a mass, it still accelerates. Inductors oppose changes in current. And yet, when we apply voltage to an inductor, the current changes.

Comment: Only an infinite inductance would prevent any change of current. A resistor of infinite resistance would be a perfect insulator with zero current.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The E field opposes a change in H field current.
- The inductor current cannot change instantly

Using a high side switch below,  the voltage rises negatively with a spike instantly with the opposite polarity from a switch open.

The drop in current is especially fast with a dry contact open switch opening at V= L*dI/dt.

So as dt goes to zero. -V is very large for a +I going to 0 as the switch opens. (using electrical std. flow not electron flow)

This generates many negative kV from a high side switch and many positive kV from a low side switch.

[image]

Normally all switches ( and FETs and wire) have a capacitance which will result in an \$f= 1/(2\pi  {(LC)}^{0.5})[Hz]\$ resonance with an envelope decay rate of L/R=T [s].

The inductor current appears to stop fast in the slow pulse rise but actually decays at the rate of T=L=100uH/(1 kohm) = 100 ns  If it was only 1 ohm shunt decay then it would be 100 uH / (1+1) [us].

[Speed up plot and repeating x100](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsCmC0CMEwDpIHZIBYBsYBM2auY6AzFJFFBDAvAFADmIsmAHCHpNi%2052nnDh6AdxB8uPePEGThY6YLYQ%20yzqKFrWHNaQ0Q1ERcIDOmlTqQh4IAGYBDADYno9R9ZkfBxuUmRgAm3hkUjwATjRMcPhSNjw2UkgwvDg0eV4OOQluYQAnLxA1Y2MjegA3DM4c7UKrCFxrOvBUDVULArB6fL5jbJ4jAM7MMHJ4BrGIeMy8TCFsAH1sTHmwecxE5Yn5mWQ2eYR5vEX5vWHRhrUp60xZg0Xl1ZksBZR4TG4wd%20w8GTRktgEK38gX28EO8z2pxG1gaM0mbA4pE%20c3uKzWbGwkHmWJQRwORwWUPOViuSyEWKWaOGYT2WxQgzAEUx3yx%20OxJ3oAA9ODxQpRSPAwiBQhxZp4AEoASxcAB0TAAXSUAW2gcplAEc5YgwABXAASAHp4AB7AAWSoANHKHI5HHLFSq1ZqTNr9UbAmalfQgA)
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The current in an inductor integrates the voltage across it. Or written in the more familiar form:

$$V=L*di/dt$$

It doesn't completely oppose a change in current. You can't get an instantaneous change of current without an infinite voltage, but it's easy to get changing current in an inductor.

Putting a sinewave voltage across an inductor will result in a cosine wave of current, lagging the voltage by 90 degrees.

(ELI the ICE man is the old mnemonic device denoting that voltage leads current in an inductor and current leads voltage in a capacitor.)

Comment: But I don't understand that why we talking about it's 'oppose a change in current' characteristic. If I understood true, inductors are not 'oppose a change in current'. But they're create a magnetic field. Main purpose usage of them they're creating magnetic field?

Comment: The fact that inductors create a magnetic field is not typically the main purpose.  They are primarily used for storing energy (in the magnetic field) in power converters, and creating filters or resonant circuits. There are other more esoteric applications but those are the main ones.

Comment: @JohnD your comment appears to say that creating a magnetic field is not the main purpose but, then go on to say that a primary use is storing energy in the magnetic field.

Comment: @Andyaka Right, my point was that storing energy is the primary purpose in that case, how it does it is secondary.  If it acted the same way electrically it could store the energy in rubber bands as far as I'd care.  (I.e. I don't use the magnetic field directly in that case.) But it's kind of semantics I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty much the same as with mass in mechanics / dynamics. The mass opposes any change in the body's speed, but that doesn't mean massive bodies can't move at all. Instead, it means that:

- massive bodies cannot change their speed instantly
- changing their speed requires a certain factor (here: external force) to be applied for some time
- for a certain force, bodies with more mass require more time to achieve a given speed

Try to figure out what "force", "speed" and "mass" correspond to in your question.