# Can someone help me understand the direction of phasors?

Tags: current

I am reading a book called *Power System Analysis and Design*. I started reading it on the chapter where phasors are introduced. I can see there is a vector diagram on the bottom of this figure but I don't understand what is determining the direction of the current in each of this vectors.

Would anyone be able to help me understand or point me in the right direction? I'm sure it's something obvious that I just can't see.

[image]

I can see that because of the inductor and capacitor the current is out of phase with the voltage and that Ic and IL are in opposite directions. I would what is causing this. Do I need to review about inductors and capacitors to understand? I find my question is so specific that I am struggling to know where to look.

I know that generally the capacitor will add pi/2 radians and the inductor will subtract pi/2 radians.

Comment: Is this answer helps? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475

Comment: And this is about the inductor https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470171/how-can-there-be-a-current-without-a-voltage/470182#470182

Comment: Yes, that actually helps me visualize it better! Thank you! I think I was overthinking it too much.

Comment: Consider changing your title to match the actual question. As asked, the answer is probably just "Yes."

Answer (score 1):

> I am curious what is causing this.

It's literally the phase between the current and the voltage that makes the direction there. That's the point of the whole chapter you're reading – you'll have to finish it, then this will make sense. You don't really seem to have a very firm grasp of what a "phase" is, right now.

The physical reason is definitely explained in a book that shows these diagrams – it's the differential equations that define what an "inductor" and what a "capacitor" are.

These diagrams arbitrarily chose to use a 0 angle for the voltage phasor, and the directions of the current phasors are the phase of the current, which is a consequence of the circuit drawn.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep reading more. I think I got ahead of myself.